# MySQL: Selecting data from multiple table where there is more than one 'many to many' relationship tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

There are five tables as follows

Please refer to this db-fiddle
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7mYgFSQUFhCbUoEvpAzpM/0

**Books**

- book_id (P.K.)
- book_name

**Authors**

- author_id (P.K.)
- author_name

**Categories**

- cat_id (P.K.)
- cat_name

(where tables **Authors** and **Category** are connected to **Books** through many to many relationship)

**BookAuthor**

- bookauthor_id (P.K.)
- book_id (F.K.)
- author_id (F.K.)

**BookCategory**

- bookcat_id
- book_id (F.K.)
- cat_id (P.K.)

For a given book_id,  I want to query and get book_name, author_name, cat_name.

How can I achieve this in mysql?

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Have you tried do query?

Comment: @dwir182 I can write query using joins when there is one junction table. Here there are two. I could not apply my knowledge to write query when there are more than one (two in this case) junction tables.

Comment: When edit include your query too..

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). In a [mcve] format table initalizations as tables. Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query

```
 SELECT b.book_name, a.author_name, c.cat_name
 FROM Books b
 JOIN BookAuthor ba ON b.book_id =ba.book_id
 JOIN Authors a ON a.author_id = ba.author_id
 JOIN BookCategory bc ON bc.book_id =b.book_id 
 JOIN Categories c ON bc.cat_id = c.cat_name
 WHERE b.book_id = 101 -- specify book id
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
SELECT b.title, ba.authors, bc.categories
FROM books b LEFT  JOIN
     (SELECT ba.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) as authors
      FROM bookauthor ba JOIN
           authors a
           ON a.auth_id = ba.auth_id
      GROUP BY ba.book_id
     ) ba
     ON b.book_id = ba.book_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT bc.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as categories
      FROM bookcategory bc JOIN
           categories c
           ON bc.cat_id = c.cat_id
      GROUP BY bc.book_id
     ) bc
     ON bc.book_id = b.book_id 
WHERE b.book_id = 101 -- specify book id 
GROUP BY b.book_id, b.title;
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7mYgFSQUFhCbUoEvpAzpM/0) is a db<>fiddle.

​